# mvc 5 deploy to win10 IIS failure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-8

I would like to publish an MVC5 web application to windows 10 IIS machine.

I have successfully deployed MVC Core on that machine, but I'm unsuccessful deploying an MVC 5 application.

I created a new project and deployed it. But I get this error:

```
HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
```

I tried the following changes:

1. Adding IUSR and IIS_IUSERS access to web directory
2. Changing web.config , add `"  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>" or "  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false"/>"`

Does anybody know how to resolve this issue?

Thank you

Comment: "I have successfully deployed MVC Core on that machine", and what is "MVC Core"? Have you enabled ASP.NET 4.x feature on IIS? Also Windows 10 machine ships IIS 10, so you shouldn't use iis-8 tag.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you should make sure your application pool identity account has the enough perission to access the web application folder.

Details, you could refer to this steps:

1.Open Windows Explorer

2.Select the directory the Smartcrypt Manager is installed under (eg: c:\web\mds)

3.Right click the directory and select Properties

4.Select the Security tab

5.Click the Edit button and then Add button

6.Click the Locations button and make sure that you select your computer.

7.Enter IIS AppPool\ (eg: IIS AppPool\smartcrypt) in the Enter the object names to select: text box.

8.Click the Check Names button and click OK.

9.Check Modify under the Allow column, and click OK, and OK.

10. Add the enough permission to that folder.